# facebook messenger bot does not reply automatically

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger

I went thru all the documentation at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart and my fan page does not reply to when receiving a message conversation.

When I logged in and start conversation I get a notification on the fan page which says: Authentication successful, Sent by bot... So basically there seems that something is working... But when I type 'hello' nothing comes back from the fan page.

I dont know what I am missing, just so u know I am using this code from this repo: https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/tree/master/node

Comment: This is my server: https://facebook-bot2-lulzimfazlija.c9users.io

Comment: do you have any logs on your server ? your link is dead btw

Comment: did u check the logs of ur cloud9?  i am assuming it is  a platform...